# scaling & Rotation of shape (rectangle)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Please i want **scaling & Rotation of shape (rectangle)** from one point.

Take as an example of MS Paint.

What will be the approach for that ?

Will it be possible ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are u using UIBezierPath as a shape? If yes, use [applyTransform:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/applyTransform:) method.

Answer (score 3):

Use CGAffineTransform for that.

**Rotation:**

```
myView.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(theView.transform, degreesToRadians(45));
```

**Scaling:**

```
myView.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(theView.transform, 2.0, 2.0);
```

***By default it scale/rotate from center.***

For any point you need to set the anchor point. See example:-

```
myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```